Access other sheet's data from inside of ARRAYFORMULA
I am extracting data from other sheet and I'd like to use ARRAYFORMULA.
In sheet1, I have a sales revenue of different sites on different dates and it's been sorted by sites and dates.
I want to retrieve every site's last day's revenue.
On sheet2, I listed every site and is able to get row# of site's last day using the MATCH function. (Cloumn B)
But I can't get revenue data with such row number.
The formula I used in sheet2 Column C
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"","'sheet1'!"&ADDRESS((B2:B),2),""))

It's the best result I can get without error.
It seems it's close to answer but I am stuck.
Result of sheet2



Column A
Column B
Column C.




Site 1
2
'sheet1'!$B$2


Site 2
7
'sheet1'!$B$7



I know INDEX should solve this but it cannot be used in ARRAYFORMULA.
If anyone can help on this it will be appreciated.
Example


Since the dates are already sorted; you can go with:
=arrayformula(xlookup(A2:A9,sheet1!A:A,sheet1!C:C,,,-1))


Alternative to bring in location & revenue in one go:
=choosecols(sortn(sort(sheet1!A2:C,2,),9^9,2,1,1),1,3)



Works well. Thank you very much!

@CHYang I gather that this is your first question at Stack Overflow. See What should I do when someone answers my question?

This is another alternative with the QUERY function where the whole table in range F2:H9 is created with the formula in cell F2 which is;
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A2:C,BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(x,MAXIFS(B2:B,A2:A,x))),Datevalue(B2:B)},"Select Col1, Col2, Col3 Where Col4= Col5 And Col1 Is Not Null"))

The benefit of this alternative is; data range does not need to be ordered by ascending or descending with respect to any column.
If the data is on Sheet1 and you want to create the result table on another sheet, then on the other sheet say, Sheet2 you can use this;
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({Sheet1!A2:C,BYROW(Sheet1!A2:A,LAMBDA(x,MAXIFS(Sheet1!B2:B,Sheet1!A2:A,x))),Datevalue(Sheet1!B2:B)},"Select Col1, Col2, Col3 Where Col4= Col5 And Col1 Is Not Null"))

You can see the sample sheet from the link below:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Njbub84EqOotmCb0in635yzf2pkZ93MNuIlFwVqQvZw/edit?usp=sharing

